# Is it possible to create a template for cloudpages?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, template

Does anyone know is it possible to create a template (similar to an email template where I can put the code in behind, and have blank slots for users to pull content blocks into).
Also, Id like to know if theres a way to "Skin" the components that are already there so they follow our design guidelines?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is not possible to copy a Cloudpage, I would say no. So the workaround could be to create this template in a cloudpage and copy-paste the code an everything in a new one in which the people can pull the content.

Regarding the second question, as it is an out of the box functionality, the components cannot be modified.